# How to stop a javascript snippet in a PHP page from loading on devices with smaller screen resolutions

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, responsive-design

I have a javascript snippet loading on a WordPress page, so the language is PHP.

It looks like this:

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var primaryNav = $('body.home').find('nav.nav-primary');
        primaryNav.hide();
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > 150) {
                primaryNav.fadeIn();
            } else {
                primaryNav.fadeOut();
            }
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

The problem is that everything works great, responsively, on larger resolutions all the way down to 688px in width.

When I go down to 687 pixels in width, the menu doesn't show when scrolling down, and that's a problem.

Is there any way to basically say:

***"do not load this javascript snippet at a device resolution of 687 pixels width or less"?***

Any guidance in helping me with this on the [NCDP site](https://nationalcdp.org/) would be greatly appreciated!

**Update:**

When I incorporate Ianaya's snippet on the [NCDP](https://nationalcdp.org/):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (window.screen.availWidth > 687) {

  (function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var primaryNav = $('body.home').find('nav.nav-primary');
        primaryNav.hide();
        $(window).scroll(function() {
          if ($(this).scrollTop() > 150) {
            primaryNav.fadeIn();
          }
          else {
            primaryNav.fadeOut();
          }
        });
    });
  })(jQuery);

}
```

The menu doesn't load when scrolling down 150 pixels, when that's when the menu should show -- or, if I can hide this javascript on devices less than 688 pixels, just show the menu always.

Comment: It's not a PHP problem as PHP doesn't know your screen size. You need to use jQuery to check the screen size meets your minimum value before executing the rest of the code.

Comment: Use JS screen.width property and if condtition

Comment: If you used CSS transitions and media queries all you would need to do is toggle a class on your nav. Let the media queries determine what to show/hide

Comment: Thanks Charlietfl. I'm aware of CSS transitions and media queries, but I'm unsure how to incorporate that into a site.

Like .... @media only screen and (min-width: 687px) { .... ?

Comment: yes, that's how you would use them

Answer (score 5):

You can access [window.screen](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.screen) object to detect the device resolution:

```
if (window.screen.availWidth > 687) {

  (function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var primaryNav = $('body.home').find('nav.nav-primary');
        primaryNav.hide();
        $(window).scroll(function() {
          if ($(this).scrollTop() > 150) {
            primaryNav.fadeIn();
          }
          else {
            primaryNav.fadeOut();
          }
        });
    });
  })(jQuery);

}
```

Comment: Hey Ianaya. Thanks for taking the time to respond!  I attempted to use your code (changed to 687), and although I don't get any errors, it doesn't hide the menu upon page load, which the script is designed to do.   Thanks again!

Comment: I'm sorry, I wasn't clear, Ianaya.  The code does hide the menu on page load of devices over 687 px width, but for some reason, the menu continues to hide itself on mobile devices (687 px or less).

Like before, if I go to 688 pixels of width, the menu hides on page load (good), but then appears when scrolling down 150 pixels, which is the effect I want. 

But it just completely hides the menu on mobile devices.

Comment: Hi Nikhil . that didn't work either; 687 or under, the menu just completely disappears.